# How can I format a SKProduct price into a Swift currency string?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdecimalnumber, skproduct

If you have code such as this, then `p` will be `"2.99"`:

```
let price = 2.99
let p = String(format: "%.2f", price)
```

However, if you have code like this:

```
let priceNS: NSDecimalNumber = 2.99
let p2 = String(format: "%.2f", priceNS)
```

Then `p2` is `"0.00"`.

How can you format an `NSDecimalNumber` into a string like this? (`NSDecimalNumber` is how the price in an `SKProduct` is stored)

Comment: You should us `Decimal` rather than `NSDecimalNumber` in Swift.

Comment: @Alexander it comes from Apple StoreKit API price property

Comment: @LeoDabus They're bridged

Comment: @Alexander how does that help in code such as:  String(format: "%.2f", someSKProduct.price)

Comment: @Sausagedioxide It doesn't, but it helps in other situations by removing potentially shared mutable state

Comment: Do not hardcode this format for currency values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should format your product price using NumberFormatter and use your product locale: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506094-price

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency 
numberFormatter.locale = someSKProduct.priceLocale
let formattedPrice = numberFormatter.string(from: someSKProduct.price) ?? ""
```

Comment: `SKProduct` really contains a "price locale" instead of a currency code? That's pretty weird. The product shouldn't determine if e.g. I use `.` or `,` for the decimal separator.

Comment: @KevinBallard I don't think thats a problem considering that the user doesn't need to input any price.

Comment: It affects display, not input. If the user has their device set to French, and is purchasing something in USD, it should show up as e.g. `2,99 $US`. But if the `product.priceLocale` is `en_US` and you set that on the formatter, they'll see `$2.99` instead of `2,99 $US`.

Comment: It will always display using the locale from where the App is being bought. If I buy a product here in Brazil from US AppStore it will display `$0.99` not `R$0,99`

Comment: @KevinBallard "French" isn't a locale. Do you mean a locale of `fr_FR`, `fr_CA`, `fr_US`, or one of many other possibilities? The language part of the locale will have no real affect on the output of a currency value. It's the region part of the locale that matters. Either way, the `priceLocale` of the product should be appropriate for the user's device and the product's currency.

Comment: True, I used "French" as shorthand for `fr_FR`. In any case, it's certainly possible for `priceLocale` to be something like `fr_FR@currency=USD`, but if that's what it is, then why is it exposed as a locale at all instead of just a currency code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `NumberFormatter` to convert an `NSNumber` to a String.

```
let priceNS:NSDecimalNumber = 2.99
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
nf.string(from: priceNS) //2.99
```

Comment: Using the `.currency` style is only appropriate if you want the currency symbol (e.g. `$`) to show up. If you do, leave the locale alone and set the `currencyCode` property instead.

Comment: Depends on how the price is being shown. Maybe OP is already showing it in a context where the user knows the currency?

Comment: In any case, to expand on my previous comment, the locale affects formatting, and the `currencyCode` affects the actual currency. Don't set the locale just to force USD, that will not work properly. Besides formatting differences, this will make it show up as e.g. `$2.99` in Canada when it should be showing up as `US$2.99`. If you leave the locale alone and set `nf.currencyCode = "USD"` then you'll get the correct currency display regardless of user locale.